# Gezerah D'Rabbah in the Beit Hamikdash?

Tags: rabbis, derabanan, lulav-etrog-arba-minim, shofar

Rabbah publicized a Gezerah (command / decree) that Lulav and Shofar should not be used on Shabbat because of a fear someone may violate the Melacha of Hotzaah.

I heard that there was another case that this Gezerah applies to, and I heard it was in the Beit Hamikdash.

Does anyone know what the other Gezerah (potentially) was, and where it is found?

Comment: Megillah on Purim? That's not really Mikdash related

Comment: @DoubleAA maybe talmid heard that based on the current calendar configuration it's only relevant for Shushan Purim, which is mostly just Yerushalayim, and then transposed that to Mikdash.

Comment: I don't remember, I thought it had to with a Zerikah on the Mizbeach (but they didn't institute it maybe?).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An additional application is the prohibition to sprinkle purifying water on a tamei meis on Shabbos, even if that would allow him to offer his Korban Pesach.

[Pesachim 69a](https://www.sefaria.org/Pesachim.69a?lang=bi)

> והזאה מאי טעמא לא דחיא שבת מכדי טלטולי בעלמא הוא תדחי שבת משום פסח אמר רבה גזירה שמא יטלנה ויעבירנה ארבע אמות ברשות הרבים
>
> What is the reason that the sprinkling of purifying water does not override Shabbat? Since it involves the mere moving of the liquid, let it at least override Shabbat on account of the mitzva of the Paschal lamb. Rabba said: The prohibition against sprinkling is a rabbinic decree that was instituted lest one take the utensil containing the purifying water and carry it a distance of four cubits in the public domain, thus violating an actual Torah prohibition.